# Is NetBiscuits any good?

Tags: mobile, mobile-website, netbiscuits

Has anybody got any real world stories build mobile web sites with NetBiscuits?

Someone told me it was the next big thing in mobile development (http://www.netbiscuits.com/home) and it looks pretty good from their site. Just wondered if anybody (besides them) has actually used it.

Comment: Never heard of it. Can you perhaps provide a link or some more information about this?

Comment: Someone told me it was the next big thing in mobile development (http://www.netbiscuits.com/home) and it looks pretty good from their site.  Just wondered if anybody (besides them) has actually used it.

Comment: I'm doing research about different frameworks for developing for multiple mobile devices, and so far i must say getting basic information about NetBiscuits is hard, most frameworks have a list of what devices and development language they support either on front page or relative easy to find, i haven't found a list of devices that NetBiscuits support yet and it took me a while to find what language you could use in development, also there is no information about pricing, i can live with the price not being there but i would expect at least a notice to contact them for price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a few months time working with it, I can say that they're indeed one of the best (if not the best) out there. The support is also *insanely* quick and good.

Only thing making me stop using it is the price. Especially if you're a small company and want to use their POI feature.

However I have yet to find a good replacement. May end up rolling my own version...

Edit: Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041804/any-netbiscuits-experiences-and-opinions/5348926#5348926).

Answer (score 0):

They have created an entire xml (bml) based markup language that emulates html that has a very steep learning curve. I would seriously reconsider using it.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen it working nicely. It also supports ASP.NET controls SDK that can be used to write ASP.NET app from Visual Studio. Once this app is deployed on your premise, you can use live bridge agent to connect this app to a Live Bridge server that Net Biscuits hosts. Your app is called a backend app in this case. This is a very useful feature when you do want to have Forms capability in your app and also want it to be accessible on NetBiscuits platform.

Check http://kb.netbiscuits.com/tactile/edc/livebridge_help.html. BiscuitML is also easier to grasp.

Answer (score 0):

Look out for performance issues though. Customers in Australia have had response time issues - probably due to the Cloud Platform being located in USA/UK.